# Converting cURL to wp_remote_post not working viz privat24 API

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

trying to get the info from api by sending xml data to it.
The thing is that it is working great with cURL, but not working via wp_remote_post.
Here is the example of xml data:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <request version="1.0">
     <merchant>
     <id>151880</id>
     <signature>23f59a159bbc82</signature>
     </merchant>
     <data><oper>cmt</oper><wait>60</wait><test>0</test><payment 
     id="a9c71ad9a291209f8b77d851c4b46f9"><prop name="sd" value="07.11.2019" /> 
     <prop name="ed" value="21.11.2019" /><prop name="card" value="4242424242424242" /> 
     </payment></data>
     </request>"

    $api_uri = 'https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/rest_fiz'
```

cURL working code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: text/xml",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml),
        "Connection: close",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *",
        'Accept: text/xml'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response  = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo curl_error($ch);
    }else{
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    return $response;
```

Not working wp_remote_post code:

```
        $result = wp_remote_post($api_uri, array(
        'headers' => array(
            "Content-Type" => "text/xml",
            "Content-length" => strlen($xml),
            "Connection" => "close",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*",
            'Accept" => "text/xml'
        ),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'sslverify' => true,
        'timeout' => 100,
        'body' => $xml
    ));
    $response = $result;
    return $response['body'];
```

Also, it is working through [Rest Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxhhz.png) as well.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: do you have an authorization header set?

Comment: @demo7up yes, it is done in xml file.

Comment: Try setting this in your .htaccess file. ```SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1```

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: @demo7up thanks, not working,  but this is plugin for Woocommerce, so changes in htaccess file are not good to go :(